# How to take the updated data backup?

Tags: mysql

I have a database at mysql and the same with on the device, i want to synchronize the updated data once in a period on my device, how can i achieve this ? Please advise. 
I got one worst case solution that is writing triggers for each table and update the details to another table, but i have 20 tables i need to write 4 trigger operations on each table, so overall 80 triggers i need to write, can anyone tell me the solution.Please help

Comment: Can't you just take mysqldump or is that not possible for you?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the mysqldump command (It's not an SQL command, it's a command-line tool).

Comment: why should i take all the data and insert it on the device again, i need to take only the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a program in your favorite programming language and let it copy the data, the program is started via cron job every X period.

Comment: So your program has to find the delta... Or you can write log information to restore the changes later...

Comment: Yes of course, and this might be the similar problem to all the mobile developers who are developing thick client applications ? There should be a solution to synchronize. isn't it ?

Comment: hey tobiask, i have checked the log also, but it is printing only the operations which we performed on tables, it's not maintaining date and time stamp, and it is generating with lot of special characters, can be very tedious to read the log file and perform the operation.